# winforms multi rows validation

Tags: .net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I've got GridView with list that consist of `MyEntity` objects. MyEntity implements `IDataErrorInfo` interface and I've got basic validation feature working.

How would I implement cross row validation feature?

For example, I've got requirement that if any on the list of `MyEntity` object contains specific value let's say `MyEntity.SomeValue = 4`, then any other rows cannot have this values again in `MyEntity.SomeValue` and after user chose this value, then red cross should appear with error message tooltip.

It looks like IDataErrorInfo is good for single row validation. I have also tried `MyGridView.ValidatingEditor += SomeMethod`

but `ValidatingEditor` prevents row from losting focus which I have requirement to be possible.

How can I approach that? Some hints?

Comment: What behavior do you expect when a constraint violated on a row? Should this new value be discarded ?

Comment: @IliaMaskov standard red cross should appear with tooltip with custom message that this value cannot be duplicated

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can create a model containing a property of type `BindingList<YourEntity>` and also implement `IDataErrorInfo` to raise validation errors for the list. Also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged` in `ListChanged` event of the `BindingList` to make sure the validation of the list will be raised by each change in elements of the list.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
public class ProductListModel : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ProductListModel(IEnumerable<Product> data)
    {
        Products = new BindingList<Product>(data.ToList());
        Products.ListChanged += (s, e) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Products)));
    }
    public BindingList<Product> Products { get; private set; }
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == nameof(Products))
                if (Products.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Any(x => x.Count() > 1))
                    return "Product names should be unique";
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not claiming it's the best idea, but it works. Also if you are using data-binding, it's ready for data-binding. Also if you are interested in validation attributes, you may find [this post](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/) useful.